# Why inner radius of housing washer and shaft washer is different in thrust bearing?

Tags: thrust

Why inner radius of the housing washer and shaft washer is different in thrust bearing?
I checked on SKF's website dimensions of a thrust bearing. The inner radius of the housing washer is different than the shaft washer inner radius. Can any you tell why is that?

Comment: So that the bearing works as a bearing.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Provide an image explaining exactly what you are discussing.

Answer (score 0):

The race with a tighter inner diameter is meant to press onto a shaft and transmit the thrust load from the shaft into the bearing elements. The housing race has a looser bore and is meant to clear the shaft so it does not accept any thrust from the shaft, this race is typically a press into your housing.